# R6010 Error after executed. If statements in for loop. [Homework] [abort resolved, new issue discovered]

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I am creating a program to encrypt or decrypt a message. The program executes but returns with a R6010 error, so I'm assuming something is wrong with the conditions I am giving. However, the program keeps running once or twice perfect before the abort starts to be called.

I'm using visual studio for C++. Still in the beginning stages/having trouble understanding some of the solutions other give for R6010 abort errors.
Maybe my code is too sloppy, but I am hoping for some advice to either clean it up, or at least pass the abort. Thank you.

***Edits from original code; corrected array size, had overflow checked first in loop(corrected abort error incase character couldnt be found), changed for loop to do-while loop, as well as changed the 0 to a -1 on if statements (do-while let the program initialize as i=0, and -1 is necessary before the loop restarts with a ++i increment).

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;



 int main() {


//Initiate vectors, strings and variables.
vector<char> normalV(27);
vector<char> cipherV(27);
string toDec;
int i = 0, j = 0;
//Initiate string & decipher variables.

normalV.at(0) = 'a'; cipherV.at(0) = '!';
normalV.at(1) = 'b'; cipherV.at(1) = '^';
normalV.at(2) = 'c'; cipherV.at(2) = '&';
normalV.at(3) = 'd'; cipherV.at(3) = '*';
normalV.at(4) = 'e'; cipherV.at(4) = '@';
normalV.at(5) = 'f'; cipherV.at(5) = '(';
normalV.at(6) = 'g'; cipherV.at(6) = ')';
normalV.at(7) = 'h'; cipherV.at(7) = '-';
normalV.at(8) = 'i'; cipherV.at(8) = '#';
normalV.at(9) = 'j'; cipherV.at(9) = '_';
normalV.at(10) = 'k'; cipherV.at(10) = '=';
normalV.at(11) = 'l'; cipherV.at(11) = '+';
normalV.at(12) = 'm'; cipherV.at(12) = '[';
normalV.at(13) = 'n'; cipherV.at(13) = '{';
normalV.at(14) = 'o'; cipherV.at(14) = '$';
normalV.at(15) = 'p'; cipherV.at(15) = ']';
normalV.at(16) = 'q'; cipherV.at(16) = '}';
normalV.at(17) = 'r'; cipherV.at(17) = ';';
normalV.at(18) = 's'; cipherV.at(18) = ':';
normalV.at(19) = 't'; cipherV.at(19) = ',';
normalV.at(20) = 'u'; cipherV.at(20) = '%';
normalV.at(21) = 'v'; cipherV.at(21) = '<';
normalV.at(22) = 'w'; cipherV.at(22) = '.';
normalV.at(23) = 'x'; cipherV.at(23) = '>';
normalV.at(24) = 'y'; cipherV.at(24) = '/';
normalV.at(25) = 'z'; cipherV.at(25) = '?';



//Get user to input string
cout << "Input message to encrypt/decrypt: " << endl;
getline(cin, toDec);


//creates loop to check for each index of 
do  {
    //cout << toDec.at(i) << endl;

    //output if character not in encryption/decryption vectors.
    if (i == 26) {
        cout << toDec.at(j);
        i = -1;
        j++;
    }

    //  Encryption
    else if (normalV.at(i) == toDec.at(j)) {
        cout << cipherV.at(i);
        i = -1;
        j++;
    }

    // Decryption
    else if (cipherV.at(i) == toDec.at(j)) {
        cout << normalV.at(i);
        i = -1;
        j++;
    }

    ++i;
} while (j < toDec.length());

cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not see a `main` in your function, so we cannot compile it independently.  Also, the error will likely depend on what input you provided.  What input did you give your program? What output did you expect? What output did you actually get?

Comment: Your condition `if (i == 27)` comes too late. And what about index 26? Or if `j++`happens to give `toDec.length()` in the first `if`?

Comment: Post a complete program that we can cut and paste and then compile and execute. Post the input that causes the problem, and a description of the wanted behavior and what it actually does.

Comment: Seriously, you don't need 26 separate lines of code.  2 lines of code and a 2 line `for` loop.  Total -- 4 lines.  Or if directly initializing the vector, 2 lines of code.  Writing these things in the way you've written them is a large cause of bugs, due to mistyping or other human error.  The less repetitive or close to repetitive code you write, the less chance there are of bugs.

Comment: `cipherV.at(24) = '//';` does not seem appropriate to me.  forward slash can be written directly as `cipherV.at(24) = '/';`.  Perhaps you meant back-slash, which does need escaping, as `cipherV.at(24) = '\\';`??

Comment: I have updated the code. I no longer get the abort error, but I've discovered some of the trouble takes place when i = 0. The 'a' will not encrypt and the '!" will only decrypt once. 


I know there has to be a way to make this a shorter code, but this was the recommended method and it's relatively easy to see whats supposed to be taking place.

Comment: After setting `i` to 0, `i++` within `for(...)` is executed before next iteration..

Comment: So I gave up with the for loop after trying to int i as -1. Instead I opted for a do-while and after each successful if or if-else it would reset to -1, then increment +1 at the end of the loop. Please provide feedback if you have a better solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler outline:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::map<char, char> encoding = {
    {'a', '!'},
    {'b', '^'},
    {'c', '&'},
    {'d', '*'},
    {'e', '@'},
    {'f', '('},
    {'g', ')'},
    {'h', '-'},
    {'i', '#'},
    {'j', '_'},
    {'k', '='},
    {'l', '+'},
    {'m', '['},
    {'n', '{'},
    {'o', '$'},
    {'p', ']'},
    {'q', '}'},
    {'r', ';'},
    {'s', ':'},
    {'t', ','},
    {'u', '%'},
    {'v', '<'},
    {'w', '.'},
    {'x', '>'},
    {'y', '/'},
    {'z', '?'} };

string toDec;


//Get user to input string
cout << "Input message to encrypt/decrypt: " << endl;
getline(cin, toDec);

    for(char c : toDec )
    {
        cout << encoding.at(c);
    }

return 0;
}
```